# Replacing Column with an Identical Column Inside a Formula

Tags: excel

Is there any way in Excel to 'paste' a formula over a column so that each cell receiving the formula is taken as input in the formula?  For example, I would like to write =Text() over a range without first putting Text(A1) over an empty column, dragging it down, and pasting the results into the original column.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Comment: are you open to code?

Comment: Definitely!  I was initially wondering if there was a way to do it without code but I can't seem to find it discussed anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that replaces a column of values with a column of formulas:

```
Sub Formulate()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, dq As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    dq = Chr(34)
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=Text(" & v & "," & dq & "mm/dd/yyyy" & dq & ")"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, would you happen to be able to explain how to modify the formula being used?  I am not very familiar with the " & v $" syntax used.  What is dq.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Stopwatch:  the **&** is a concatenation of pieces of strings.  the **dq** is an in-line double-quote.

Comment: Thanks!  So would it be much the same to modify the code and have it use the =Sum function, for example?

Comment: As an example, =SUM(A1,B3,C6).